# How do I access image stored on a local server from an android application?

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, picasso

I am trying to use picasso library to load images to imageView but the image is not stored on the phone nor is it stored online. It is stored in a PC in a local network. From the info I gathered I have to host all what I need on local http server and access it like I would an image online.I also don't want to store an image directly to a db since it's not efficient. The best way it seems is to use spring boot to access the file and provide http link. I tried to create the server but I don't fully understand how to send files over http. I already have the link to the image ("http://192.168.1.33:8080/file/454626.jpg") but it doesn't work and when i try it on the browser on the phone it downloads the image directly. How do I simply view the image and not download it? I'm sorry I'm a beginner to Spring framework. Also can anybody point me to where I can learn more about this particular problem? I've seen the tutorials on spring.io but I can't seem to find a tutorial about sending images.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class FileDownloadController {
    String folderPath="C:/Program Files (x86)/Wowza Media Systems/Wowza Streaming Engine 4.8.0/content/Posters/";


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showFiles(Model model) {
        File folder = new File(folderPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        model.addAttribute("files", listOfFiles);
        return "showFiles";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/file/{fileName}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void show(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {


        if (fileName.indexOf(".jpg")>-1) response.setContentType("application/jpg");

          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +fileName);
          response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
          try {
              BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(folderPath+fileName);
              int len;
              byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
              while((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                  bos.write(buf,0,len);
              }
              bos.close();
              response.flushBuffer();
          }
          catch(IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

          }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

> the image is not stored on the phone nor is it stored online. It is stored in a PC in a local network.

Your image is actually stored "online" since it's on an online network and to access it you use a server.

You're mentioning using `Picasso`, have you try doing  something like `Picasso.get().load("http://192.168.1.33:8080/file/454626.jpg").into(imageView);` ?

Comment: yes i did that. But its not working. I added a print command inside the onerror method and it displays which suggests to me that there was a problem in loading the image.

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. I hope my solution would help anyone who is having a problem similar to mine. I did it by taking a different approach. I followed this tutorial http://zetcode.com/springboot/serveimage/ to better understand springboot's handling of images. More importantly I found out that you need to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application manifest in-order to make http calls within the android app. A better solution is to make the local server https compatible since it's more secure. That'll be the next step.